# Use std::bitset to produce binary file

Tags: c++, cout, bitset

I am using `std::bitset` to give me a binary representation of a number. I now want to use this and output to `std::cout` using only the binary representation - I *do not* want the ASCII representation of `std::bitset` - I merely want to output my bitset as it is in memory.

```
bitset<32> bits = a;
cout << bits; //produces the ASCII characters for '1' and '0' depending on a
```

Comment: what is you expected output?

Comment: My expected output would be garbage when you look at it's ascii representation - but if you were to look at its binary representation, it would be something like 10101011101010111010101110101011

Comment: so you want get raw data out of it? only way is `to_ulong` and `to_ullong`, which won't work for large bitset

Comment: bits is giving back numeric 0,1, i tried it and test this.  this prints -48, -47 , if it was ascii 0 and 1, i would have got 0,1  for (int i = 0; i < bits.size(); ++i)
    { 
        cout << (bits[i]-'0')  ;
    }

Comment: Honestly, `bitset` is a bit junk.  Find another solution.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your intent but did you try [std::bitset::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string)? It returns a string of the binary representation.

Answer (score 0):

If your bitset is within the limits of the function `to_ulong` or `to_ullong`, you can use those functions and output those to a binary file directly.

If your bitset exceeds the amount that an `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` can store, the function will throw an overflow exception. This means that you need to extract subsets of the bitset, and for each subset store the `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` to file.

Unfortunately `std::bitset` does not provide a direct subset function, so you would have to write that yourself.